# I'm new and would like some help racking my brain around how to structure an OOP "template", I'll use an example --

Tags: python, oop

Let's say I make a game, where the ocean is my environment. So:

```
class Ocean:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Next, I'd create another class, (not a child class, as I learned from you guys earlier):

```
class Fish:
    def __init__(self, pounds, length):
        pass
```

But now, I'd like to make a subclass here:

```
class Trout(Fish):
    def __init__(self, fave_bait, fave_geo_loc):
        super().__init__(self, pounds, length)
        self.fave_bait = []
        self.fave_geo_loc = []

    def swim():
        pass

    def attack():
        pass
```

Alright, all this said, THIS is where I fall apart. I have no idea how to start implementing logic in this framework. I suppose maybe I'm supposed to do stuff like `swim = False`, and tie that to some if statement, and then something else. But I really have a hard time "seeing" and visualizing what I'm supposed to do while looking at this from a bird's eye view.

I believe I'm supposed to parse all of this into smaller chunks, maybe create a mind map, but I'm lost. I just need to know how **you yourself** personally think through the process of executing piece by piece all this code.

I feel like I know *what* everything is, but now I'm stuck on *how* to put everything together.

Comment: seems you're asking oop and design patterns, not python.

Comment: I started coding a month ago, I'm only familiar with python. But I practice 10 hours a day because I'm trying to make a game. It's going to be a pretty big game though so I have to get this stuff down.

Comment: you can learn by exploring existing open source games. it should be faster than inventing everything from scratch.

Comment: Are there examples of stuff on this website I can check out? I just found out about this website today and received a ton of help with my first question. ✌️

Comment: how about some books such as *head first oop*

Comment: In your example, where is the subclass supposed to find out its `pounds` and `length` (and why do you mix the name of the measurement with the unit of the measurement in the variable names (let alone then not use SI units for weight))?

Comment: I would advise that you remove the parentheses after `Ocean` and `Fish` as you won't be directly inheriting from any class (other than the indirect inheritance from `object` of course). `swim` and `attack` methods probably need a `self` argument as well.

Answer (score 0):

"I have no idea how to start implementing logic in this framework" -Logic goes into the class methods, and data into class members. The idea of the class is to combine data and related methods together, and hide unnecessary implementation details from the users. If you will have various types of fish in your game, it might make sense to implement them as classes and put the individual data of each fish type into its own class. But you still need to decide what you concretely want to accomplish. Abstract fish will not do anything. For example, if the fish need to appear on the screen, you need to give the `Fish` class a concrete `render()` method that will render it on screen.

Also, all of your code will not be in the class methods. You will also have code outside any class that will create and manipulate fish etc. Classes are just a tool to help to organize your code. Their use is not mandatory. In fact, using too many classes can be detrimental. Beginners tend to write dozens of thin classes for no reason, just making the code very difficult for everybody else to read.